# using RenderScript from NDK in Xamarin app

Tags: android, renderscript

I built this sample https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/tests/device/rs-cpp-basic/ using ndk as shared library then added it with the dependency "libRSSupport.so, libRSSupportIO.so, libblasV8.so" to the app and execute test_compute() but the app crash, Here meaningful part of logcat I got:

```
2267 I rstest-compute: New RS 0x9f187000
2267 E RS Dispatch: Couldn't initialize dispatchTab.ScriptReduce
2267 V rsC++   : libRS.so init failed!
2267 I rstest-compute: Init returned 1
2267 I rstest-compute: Element 0x9f30e950
2267 I rstest-compute: Type 0x9f129c60
2267 I rstest-compute: Allocation 0x9f30e9f0
2267 I rstest-compute: Allocation 0x9f30ea40 0x9f30ea90
2284 E RenderScript: Unable to open shared library (/data/user/0/App1.Android//lib/librs.mono.so): (null)
2284 E RenderScript: Unable to open system shared library (/system/lib/librs.mono.so): (null)
2267 I rstest-compute: new script
2267 E rsC++   : Internal error: Object id 0.
2267 E rsC++   : Internal error: Object id 0.
2267 E rsC++   : Internal error: Object id 0.
2267 E rsC++   : Internal error: Object id 0.
2267 E rsC++   : Internal error: Object id 0.
2267 E rsC++   : Internal error: Object id 0.
2267 E rsC++   : Internal error: Object id 0.
2284 E mono-rt : /proc/self/maps:
2267 E rsC++   : Internal error: Object id 0.

2284 E mono-rt :
2284 E mono-rt : No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).
2284 E mono-rt :
2284 E mono-rt :
2284 E mono-rt : =================================================================
2284 E mono-rt : Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
2284 E mono-rt : a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
2284 E mono-rt : used by your application.
2284 E mono-rt : =================================================================
2284 E mono-rt :
2284 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x2c in tid 2284 (App1.Android)
212 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
212 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j1minive3gjv/j1minive3g:6.0.1/MMB29Q/J106HJVU0AQB3:user/release-keys'
212 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
212 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
212 F DEBUG   : pid: 2267, tid: 2284, name: App1.Android  >>> App1.Android <<<
212 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x2c
212 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 9f1afe00  r3 00000003
212 F DEBUG   :     r4 00000001  r5 9f12d000  r6 ffffffff  r7 00000000
212 F DEBUG   :     r8 9ed71080  r9 9f12d21c  sl 9f12d1f8  fp 00000008
212 F DEBUG   :     ip 9ee610dc  sp 9ed71048  lr 9edd8d55  pc 9edd4eb0  cpsr 800f0030
212 F DEBUG   :
212 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
212 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00062eb0  /data/app/App1.Android-1/lib/arm/libRSSupport.so (_ZN7android12renderscript6Script9setVarObjEjPNS0_10ObjectBaseE+7)
212 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00066d53  /data/app/App1.Android-1/lib/arm/libRSSupport.so (_ZN7android12renderscript8ThreadIO16playCoreCommandsEPNS0_7ContextEi+238)
212 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0005ea87  /data/app/App1.Android-1/lib/arm/libRSSupport.so (_ZN7android12renderscript7Context10threadProcEPv+466)
212 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0003f83b  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+30)
212 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00019fdd  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
2291 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity App1.Android/md58adf3f2592a7497b73592b5e766304c2.MainActivity
212 F DEBUG   :
212 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_03
212 E DEBUG   : AM write failed: Broken pipe
1653 I BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_03 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
212 E         : ro.product_ship = true
212 E         : ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
2291 D InputDispatcher: Focused application set to: xxxx
212 E         : sys.mobilecare.preload = false
2645 E audit   : type=1701 msg=audit(1491844085.913:437): auid=4294967295 uid=10112 gid=10112 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=2284 comm="App1.Android" reason="memory violation" sig=11
2291 D ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger
253 I Zygote  : Process 2267 exited due to signal (11)
```

If i change the library name to `rs.mono` these errors disappear:

```
2284 E RenderScript: Unable to open shared library (/data/user/0/App1.Android//lib/librs.mono.so): (null)
2284 E RenderScript: Unable to open system shared library (/system/lib/librs.mono.so): (null)
```

Also after some testing I noticed `sp<ScriptC_mono> sc = new ScriptC_mono(rs);` cause the crash
I'm sure i miss something but i don't know what it is, I read somewhere that must include .rs files in package, Is that correct in my case?
Also I ignore .bc files but since it's bytecode I think it's java related stuff.

However I use samsung j1 mini prime(marshmallow 6.0.1) to deploy the app and ndk-r14b and build tools version 23.0.3

Comment: The `.rs` files contain your C99 RenderScript code. Which assuming the standard Android toolchain will output LLVM bitcode in  `.bc` files. Not having `.bc` files in your package means that you are missing code.

Comment: I added `.bc` file as AndroidNativeLibrary alongside other shared libraries but app still crash with same errors.

Comment: As Xamarin doesn't support `user script RenderScript`: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/renderscript/ I'm not sure if it knows how to package the files correctly. One path to explore may be to do a simple RenderScript with Android NDK project (standard Android SDK/NDK) and see what are the differences between the apk built by the Android tool chain and a Xamarin build NDK project.

Comment: I take a look to the generated apk, It's have `librsrt.bc` and `mono.bc` which i grabbed from `obj\local\armeabi-v7a\objs\mono` in `lib\armeabi-v7a` inside apk, I don't know if that the correct place. anyway I really have zero experience in building apk outside Visual Studio, I wonder if you can point me out to ready apk that have `.bc` files included so I can do some comparisons. thanks in advance.

Comment: You should build the rs files with ndk-build first. Then select the correct type of binary or source file you want to use and linked with your project. I don't have example with Xamarin. but I have successfully build with bazel and Gradle. Checkout here: [BazelRenderScript](https://github.com/EE202B/BazelRenderScript) and [bazel link prebuilt lib](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2638#issuecomment-288348875). I think your case probably go with the first one: using shared library.

Comment: Thank you very much for the project, the app is working fine now. Actually all what i missed is `LOCAL_RENDERSCRIPT_COMPATIBILITY := true` which generate `librs.mono.so` in `obj\local\armeabi-v7a`, I added that file to the package and everything is working as smoothly as required.

Comment: Do you have a working sample in any repository with Xamarin?

Comment: No, but there are a scribble working sample in my local drive. Not sure if you really want that.